# Shell скрипт - не запускается из-за ерунды (unexpected end of line)

Tags: shell, bash

Добрый день, коллеги!

Имеется вот такой shell скрипт

```
1    if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
2       echo "Echo Message 1"
3       echo "Echo Message 2"
4       exit 1
5    fi
6    
7    if [ ! -x "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java ]; then
8       echo "Echo Message 3"
9       echo "Echo Message 4"
10      exit 1
11   fi
12    
13    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
14      echo "Echo Message 5: OK"
15      exit 1
16    fi
17
18    if [ ! -x "$1" ]; then
19      echo "Message 6: You supplied $1"
20      exit 1
21    fi
22    
23    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
24      echo "Message 7 : OK"
25      exit 1
26    fi
27    
28    if [ ! -x "$2" ]; then
29      echo "Message 8: You supplied $2"
30      exit 1
31    fi
32   
33    for i in "$2"/*.jar
34    do
35      CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
36    done
37    
38    _EXECJAVA = "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java
39    CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME"/lib/tools.jar
40    
41    _EXEC="$_EXECJAVA -classpath "$CLASSPATH"
42    com.example.test.Transaction $3"
43    
44    $_EXEC
```

Вылетает с ошибкой с намеком на синтаксис.

line 44: syntax error: unexpected end of line

Что я делаю не так?

Done поменял на FI - одно и тоже

Comment: `if` завершается `fi`, а не `done`.

Comment: @avp - менял, тоже самое

Comment: С кавычками в 41-й и 42-й строках разберитесь. Перед 44-й напишите

     echo _EXEC = $_EXEC 

и посмотрите, что выводит.

--

А почему бы вместо `$_EXEC`  просто не написать

    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath $CLASSPATH

--

Кстати, в строке 39 Вы что-то не то пишите. Она результат цикла в строках с 33 по 36 перебивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обрати внимание на строчку 43 у тебя там 3 двойные кавычки, что-то не закрыто

Answer (score 0):

А еще линукс совсем не любит, когда самая последняя строчка непустая ;)